# raw_input check to allow for reinitiation of same function

Tags: python, raw-input

I was banging my head against my desk on this one, because I'm an idiot, and I've finally gotten it to work. This is a simplified, dumb version of my actual code (which is why the function's purpose seems so inane) but I'm curious whether there is (or rather, am sure there must be) a more efficient way of doing the following:

```
def get_char():
    character = raw_input("Enter the character you would like to use.\n >")
    if character.isalpha:
        proceed = raw_input("The value entered is " + character + "\nWould you like to proceed?(Y/N)\n>")
        while True:
            if proceed in "N,n":
                raw_input("Press enter to try again with another value.")
                character = get_char()
                break
            else:
                break
    return character
    #print character

character = get_char()
print character
```

What I want to end up with is a way of checking that the user's input is what they intended. Until I set character = get_char() in the while loop, I was getting problematic output (i.e. incorrect final values for character); having fixed that, I've noticed that if I include the print statement at the end of the get_char() definition, it prints out the number of times a "no" choice has been made +1. While the end result is still fine, I'm curious whether the fact that it seems to be holding iterations in a queue, as indicated by the multiple prints upon inclusion of the print statement, means that there's a better way of doing this. Thanks in advance for any help!

UPDATE:
Just in case anyone else needs help with this same issue, based on the suggestion by millerdev, I've adjusted the code to the following, which works just the same except without the self-call which was generating unnecessary `character` queuing:

```
def get_char():
    while True:
        character = raw_input("Enter the character you would like to use\n >")
        if character.isalpha:
            proceed = raw_input("The value entered is " + character + "\nWould you like to proceed? (Y/N)\n>")
            if proceed in ("N", "n"):
                raw_input("Press enter to try again with another value.")
            else:
                break
#print character    
return character
```

character = get_char()

Comment: Your while-loop will only run for 1 iteration.  Also, you forgot to invoke `str.isalpha`:   `if character.isalpha():`

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand: currently, the code works as intended; it can run a (presumably) infinite number of times through the loop if "N" is being chosen. Apologies if this is unclear, but the character.isalpha() check is really just for illustrative purposes; the actual check makes sense in the context of the program.

Comment: You need parens on your str.isalpha().  Also In [1]: 'N,n' in 'N,n'
Out[1]: True

Comment: What I mean is `str.isalpha` is a method.  So, it needs to be invoked by placing `()` after it.  As for the while-loop, your logic structure makes it run only once.  This is because you have two `break`s.  If `if proceed in "N,n":` comes back `True`, it breaks.  If it doesn't, it also breaks.

Comment: I'm really sorry if I'm missing something, but running `character.isalpha` with `()` after it doesn't produce the desired functionality, and that's actually beside the point: let's leave aside the particulars of `str.isalpha` as all it's there for is to produce an if statement which mirrors the actual organization of my full code. To your other point, I'm not sure what you mean by "your logic structure makes it run only once"; I have run this code exactly as written and it runs as many times as I opt to choose "N" when hitting the while loop. Am I missing something?

Comment: It appears to be "holding iterations in a queue" because you're making a recursive call to `get_char` (that is, `get_char` calls itself). I suggest that you remove the recursion and restructure your loop so it loops over the things you want to repeat.

Comment: Thanks @millerdev ; I don't know why my brain couldn't get a handle on it, but I've adjusted the code to place the while loop out further and that allows me to avoid using the recursive call. I appreciate the help! And thanks to everyone else who chimed in; I don't think my example was as clear as it could have been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of `character = get_char()`, your loop only runs once, because it will recurse deeper if it fails instead of iterating again. This probably isn't what you want, because it's slower and runs the risk of overflowing the stack. The cleanest way to do this would probably be (you could replace my messages with yours easily):

```
def get_char(is_valid = lambda c: True):
    while True:
        c = raw_input('enter a character > ')
        if is_valid(c):
            keep = raw_input('do you want to use {0}? (Y/N)> '.format(c)).lower()
            if 'n' in keep:
                continue # go back to While True line
            return c
        print('{0} is not a valid character'.format(c))
```

Session:

```
>>> get_char()
enter a character > a
do you want to use a? (Y/N)> n
enter a character > c
do you want to use c? (Y/N)> no
enter a character > x
do you want to use x? (Y/N)> y
'x'
```

At least, this is the cleanest in my opinion. Your implementation has a few other problems, like `proceed in "N,n"`, which would also count comma as an `n`, and if the character isn't `isalpha`, you still return it.

Comment: You're right about all the stuff with `proceed` and `.isalpha`, but those are minor issues. This does get to the meat of it, though, and essentially mirrors the solution I came up with after reading some other comments (I hadn't scrolled down to your reply - 'cause I'm a dummy). One interesting thing you mention is the `continue` statement; I'll have to look into that because I wasn't aware of how to use it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're aiming for?

```
def get_char():
    while True:
        character = raw_input("Enter the character you would like to use.\n >")
        if character.isalpha: # this is always true; add parens if that's what you want, otherwise remove it
            proceed = raw_input("The value entered is " + character + "\nWould you like to proceed? (Y/n)\n>")
            if proceed.lower() == "n":
                raw_input("Press enter to try again with another value.")
                character = get_char()
            return character

character = get_char()
print character
```